# Java using a method value to subtract a object field value

Tags: java, variables, if-statement, methods

my quick question is.

how would i be able to allow this method to return its damageDelt value? i want to use this value to be able to subtract from another class field variable hitpoint value. how can i do this? as i would like this method to reduce the hitpoints from another objects hitpoints.

Thank you

```
package com.DavidLee.Programming;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Main().railGunAttack();
        System.out.println();

    }

    public void railGunAttack() {

        int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);

        if (randomNumber > 0 && randomNumber < 50) {
            int damageDelt = 2 * randomNumber;
            System.out.println("Railgun did " + damageDelt + " Damage");
        } else if (randomNumber > 50 && randomNumber < 80) {
            int damageDelt = 4 * randomNumber;
            System.out.println("Railgun did " + damageDelt + " Damage");
        } else if (randomNumber > 80 && randomNumber < 100) {
            int damageDelt = 50 - randomNumber;
            System.out.println("Railgun did " + damageDelt + " Damage " + "Railgun projectiles glazed the target");
        } else
            System.out.println("Railgun missed target");
    }
}
```

Comment: `public int railGunAttack()` and `return damageDelt;` (or `0`) as appropriate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Um... Change it from `public void` to `public int`, and add a `return damageDelt;` at the end?

Comment: if i change to public int railGunAttack and add the return damageDelt; i get the - cannot resolve symbol 'damageDelt'

Comment: please change the title of this question to have some descriptive value

Comment: it's "dealt", not "delt", by the way.

Comment: Declare `damageDealt` at the beginnig of the method, rather than inside each `if` block.

Comment: Learn what `else` means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments have suggested you need to change the return type of the function to return `int` and you need to return your `damageDelt` variable.  One way to do this is declare it outside of your `if` statements and then return it at the end of the function.  If you didn't want to do it that way you could add a `return` statement inside each of your `if` blocks but that would be a bit messy.
So your function might look like this:

```
public int railGunAttack() {

    int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
    int damageDelt = 0;

    if (randomNumber > 0 && randomNumber < 50) {
        damageDelt = 2 * randomNumber;
        System.out.println("Railgun did " + damageDelt + " Damage");
    } else if (randomNumber > 50 && randomNumber < 80) {
        damageDelt = 4 * randomNumber;
        System.out.println("Railgun did " + damageDelt + " Damage");
    } else if (randomNumber > 80 && randomNumber < 100) {
        damageDelt = 50 - randomNumber;
        System.out.println("Railgun did " + damageDelt + " Damage " + "Railgun projectiles glazed the target");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Railgun missed target");
    }
    return damageDelt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the return type of the method and in the method reference the variable or object you want to return.

Example: 
public int age(){
  int UserAge = 100;

return UserAge;
}